# Struggling to configure sendmail right with email on same domain

Tags: email, sendmail, user-accounts

I have a situation that probably unusual.

I run a handful of services I find useful at my domain `example.com`. `example.com` is pointed to my VPS server via A record and it's associated services work fine (for example, `ircd`).

The only service I don't run is mail through this server because I do not trust the reliability (nor security) of the company enough to do that. So I host my mail over at protonmail. I pointed the MX records in my domain to `example.com` properly, and I can indeed receive mail there.

The problem comes with my mail daemon on the server. I want to set up, among other things, tripwire to alert me of unusual activity on the server. Everything works fine up to the point where I do:

> command | mail -s "subject from `uname -n`" me@example.com.

Unfortunately, `me@example.com`, which is a email, is getting confused for a local user (as indicated by error code 67). This is problematic because I don't host my email through this server.

Is there any way I can create an alias for the user `me@example.com` to point to an email so I can receive email in my actual inbox rather than having to login and use `mail`? Strangely, `fail2ban` didn't have these problems - I got a `fail2ban started` email when I set it up without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your host's hostname is set incorrectly. It should never be set to the naked domain name.

To solve the problem, rename the host, e.g. to `www.example.com` or anything containing a fully qualified domain name, and then restart sendmail.

Your DNS records do not change, only the system's local hostname.

Comment: This is useful, thank you. Is it normal to name the server the `www` variant?

Comment: I unmarked your answer because after renaming my hostname, which the command `hostname` now returns "www" I still get an error 67. If you could elaborate I will happily recheck. (the command `echo hello world | mail -s "subject here" me@example.com` still returns 67).

Comment: @CL40 Did you restart sendmail? What's in your sendmail.mc?

Comment: I did, unfortunately it didnt fix it. The only relevant line I saw was `MASQUERADE_AS(\`example.com\`)` which I change the `example.com` argument to `www.example.com` and started sendmail via `systemctl restart sendmail` with no effect :/.

Comment: Hm, that shouldn't be there at all, so removing it is appropriate. Interesting that you are still having the problem though. Hmm.